# Exposing docker port forwarded via SSH

Tags: docker, ssh, docker-compose, alpine-linux

I'm using a container from docker hub which is Alpine with ssh-client installed. I'm trying to forward an https service on a remote network and assign it to a local IP using macvlan. I'm using the following docker compose:

```
version: '3.3'

networks:
    vlan100:
        driver: macvlan
        driver_opts:
            parent: enp3s0
        ipam:
            config:
                - subnet: 192.168.0.0/24

services:
    dsm-over-ssh:
        container_name: dsm-over-ssh
        volumes:
            - '~/.ssh:/root/.ssh'
        command:
            - '-L 443:192.168.1.3:5001'
            - '-4'
            - 'user@server.com'
        networks:
            vlan100:
                ipv4_address: 192.168.0.133
        tty: true
        image: occitech/ssh-client
```

So the idea is to start a container that perpetually has `ssh -L 443:192.168.1.3:5001 -4 user@server.com` running.

When I run `docker exec -ti dsm-over-ssh /bin/sh`, `apk add curl`, `curl https://localhost -k` it displays the code for the correct site.

However when I try to visit https://192.168.0.133 from a browser on a different computer on the same network it eventually times out and says failed to connect.

I'm able to load other sites hosted on the same vlan on the same server. I've tried setting the port to 443:443 instead, and it still fails with https://192.168.0.133.

If I try curl from another device on the same network I get `curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server`.

I'm probably missing something simple here, anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like other server-type processes running in Docker containers, your ssh forwarder needs to be configured to listen on the special 0.0.0.0 "all interfaces" address; and like many server-type processes, it defaults to listening on the 127.0.0.1 "only the container-private localhost" address.  See the description of the `-L` option in [**ssh**(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh), and the description of the `GatewayPorts` setting in [**ssh_config**(5)](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config).

This means you need to specify the alternate bind address in your forwarder:

```yaml
command:
    - '-L0.0.0.0:443:192.168.1.3:5001'
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! I knew it was going to be obvious to someone what I was missing. This answer solved my problem :)